# Hive pause and resume task

Tags: hadoop, hive

## My question

I am new in Hive and Hadoop environment. I want to pause and resume Hive job running on Hadoop.

## What have I tried

I want some ideas related to same.  What I am thinking is I might save the state of mappers and reducer if feasible.

But I do not know how to keep track of mapper and reducer. I have found some interfaces and classes in hadoop like JobId, JobClient Which can help in keeping track of same. I also read some Workflow kind of stuff for tracing each task but not much clarity.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I see some close votes for it being too broad, perhaps because the bottom part (what has been tried) seems a bit broad. However, the first part is a quite straightforward question.

Answer (score 0):

## This is practically impossible

If I am not mistaken a Hive job
(or any hadoop mapreduce job for that matter) can be waiting, running or finished (either succesfully, or failed).

There is normally no way to pause a hive job and continue.
There is definitely not a 'debug shortcut' like in some languages that would allow you to pause processing in the middle of a step, and I have not seen breakpoints either.

## But here is how you can get close

#### 1. Split the job

This is the practical (though limited) approach.

Rather than making one hive script, make 2 and just run the first one. The first one could do part of the steps, or could only operate on part of the data, effectively allowing you to 'pause'. Resuming would then be running the complementary second script.

(If you want you can use a scheduler to start the first one, then some time later or after a trigger start the second one, but I would start simple)

#### 2. Freeze the complete environment

This is not very practical for most intents and purposes, but may be possible and could be usefull for resource purposes.

You can perhaps freeze the whole cluster, this should be possible halfway a select or so, if you really want to look in depth.

How to do this (and investigate the state of the system) would not be a question regarding hive, but the whole OS of all nodes. If you only have 1 node, I suppose it could be straightforward by putting it into a virtual machine.

Comment: .Thanks lot . I want to expand the scope of the requirement. Its like in my current functionality we   call  hive UDF which basically fetches data from different tables as per the logic. Now if UDF does full processing for around 10 minutes and gets all results. But in between I felt I do not want to continue the job so wanted to Pause so that can resume later when feels important. While doing pause I need  to store partial results  which function has rendered already.On next resume UDF function should eliminate already rendered results and start processing  on pending data.